# Hacer que un ListView ocupe todo el espacio disponible

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente código para generar el ListView:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:30),
          child: RefreshIndicator(
            child: SizedBox(
              height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: model.state == ViewState.Busy ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: model.farmerList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_,index)
                  {
                    return  Padding(
(Interior del list view)

            
          ),
        )
```

y el Body es el siguiente:

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: false,
          child: Column(
            children:  [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
```

Como veis en el list view estoy usando `MediaQuery`, lo cual entiendo que me debería coger todo el espacio disponible, sin embargo, el list view se alarga hasta el infinito. Esto creo que sucede porque en el body tengo un `SingleChildScrollView`, sin embargo, al quitar esto último, obtengo un overflow de varios pixeles (según el tamaño de la lista), y no entiendo los motivos.

> Sé que esto se ha preguntado muchas veces, pero no consigo dar con la solución aún mirando las respuestas, o es que no doy con lo que tengo que hacer exactamente.

Comment: quizás podrías agregar una imagen de lo que quieres lograr

Comment: @diegoveloper He agregado un esquema donde se ilustra mejor la pregunta.

Comment: podrías agregar ahora una imagen de como se muestra ahora, con el código que tienes?

Comment: @diegoveloper Ya la he añadido, a ver si así se entiende mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He preparado un ejemplo en base a la estructura que mencionaste, no necesitas asignarle un alto al `ListView`, solamente deja que se expanda pero usando el parámetro `shrinkWrap` para que tome el mínimo tamaño disponible.

Código:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              child: const Text(
                'HEADER',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              child: const Text(
                'BOTONES',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              // es necesario esto para cancelar el scroll interno y usar el scroll global del SingleChildScrollView
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 15,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  tileColor: Colors.green,
                  title: Text('Title: $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              child: const Text(
                'FOOTER',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas que el HEADER y FOOTER se queden estáticos y solo mover el ListView, necesitas estos cambios:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 100,
            child: const Text(
              'HEADER',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 100,
            child: const Text(
              'BOTONES',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 15,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  tileColor: Colors.green,
                  title: Text('Title: $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 100,
            child: const Text(
              'FOOTER',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Quitas el `SingleChildScrollView` ya que no necesitas que todo sea scrolleable, y usas el Expanded para expandir el `ListView` a todo el espacio disponible.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, Más o menos iria por ahí la cosa, solo que el header, los botones y el footer deberían quedarse quietos. Como podría hacer eso? Procediendo de la misma forma que has puesto?

Comment: ahí actualicé mi respuesta, si deseas aprender más : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFKZxStYsOVrzdN_FCZ0NGg/join

Comment: Sigo obteniendo un overflow: "The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type StackParentData." Creo que es relativo a como está hecha la parte del list view. Edito la pregunta con el código.

Comment: prueba el código que usé y trata de adaptarlo, recuerda que tu tienes un refreshindicator , yo use el expanded porque encima de ese widget tengo un Column, quizás tú no lo tienes, revisa bien

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, ni aún habiendo puesto encima un Column, trataré de seguir investigando...

Comment: Ya lo conseguí averiguar, se trataba del Refresh indicator que efectivamente estaba estorbando.